# zend2 required message change inside FilterInput::isValid()

Tags: forms, validation, input, zend-framework2

I'm trying to change required message inside InputFilter::isValid() method. But I have no clue how to change this particular message for one field. Here is my code:

```
class EventFormInputFilter extends InputFilter
{
    protected $dbAdapter;
    protected $isEdit = false;


    public function __construct(Adapter $dbAdapter, $isEdit = false)
    {
        $factory = $this->getFactory();
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
        $this->isEdit = $isEdit;

        $this->add($factory->createInput(
            [
                'name' => 'market_id',
                'required' => false,
                'allow_empty' => false,
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => 'Null'],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => '\AssetBase\Validator\Db\RecordExists',
                        'options' => [
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'table' => 'markets',
                            'adapter' => $dbAdapter,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ));

        $this->add($factory->createInput(
            [
                'name' => 'country_id',
                'required' => false,
                'allow_empty' => false,
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => 'Null'],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => '\AssetBase\Validator\Db\RecordExists',
                        'options' => [
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'table' => 'countries',
                            'adapter' => $dbAdapter,
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ));
    }

    public function isValid()
    {
        $marketId = $this->getValue('market_id');
        $countryId = $this->getValue('country_id');
        if (empty($marketId) && empty($countryId)) {
            $this->get('market_id')->setRequired(true);
            // how to change required error message here?
            $this->get('country_id')->setRequired(true);
            // how to change required error message here?
        }
        return parent::isValid();
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change required message in your form like as below.

```
$inputFilter = new InputFilter();
$factory = new InputFactory();
```

Create InputFilter object and apply the validation as below.

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'country_id',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        'isEmpty' => 'Country id is required.',
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )));
```